# How to prevent submission of a form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a form which contains multiple list items. I need to prevent a `li` field containing multiple input fields from being submitted.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<li id="field_1_120"><label for="input_1_120_1">Vendor Application</label>
   <div class="ginput_container">
      <input type="hidden" value="Vendor Application" name="input_120.1">
      <span>Price:</span> <span id="input_1_120" >$180.00</span>
      <input type="hidden" value="$180.00" id="ginput_base_price_1_120" name="input_120.2">
      <input type="hidden" value="1" name="input_120.3">
   </div>
</li>
```

This is how an entry is being created on the entry detail page when above code is submitted.

```
<p>Vendor Application, Qty: 1, Price: $180.00</p>
```

I tried using this jQuery to disallow hidden inputs from being submitted:

```
$('input[type=hidden]').attr('disabled',true)
```

But now entries are created like this:

```
<p>, Qty: , Price: $180.00</p>
```

I just want to get rid of the list item completely so that there is no entry created for it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And how exactly is a LI submitted ?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove "name" attribute from the input field then values will not be submitted, unless there is some more javascript collecting values by ID and passing them